# Visualise object in R as tree

Tags: r, list, tree, visualization

I would like to visualize an R object (nested list) as a tree. Consider the following list

```
x <- list(
  id = 1,
  status = "active",
  coord = list(phi=0, theta=1, r=1),
  mt = NULL
)
```

I would like to see its structure, not actual values. I can achieve this in a roundabout way using `data.tree` library:

```
library(data.tree)
dt <- list(
  name = "x",
  children = list(
    list(name = "id"),
    list(name = "status"),
    list(name = "coord",
      children = list(
        list(name = "phi"),
        list(name = "theta"),
        list(name = "r")
      )
    ),
    list(name = "mt")
  )
)

plot(FromListExplicit(dt))
```

This is the result:

[image: tree image link]

This is, however, rather complicated. The problem with this approach is that the code to create the dendrogram (object `dt`) is detached from my actual code (object `x`). As my code evolves and my objects change, I would like to have them quickly visualized (e.g., in Rmarkdown document) in their current state.

Is there any way of plotting the structure of a nested list as a tree? Or, perhaps, someone can suggest a function to convert my original object into a list appropriate for `data.tree`, that is to convert `x` to `dt`. Alas, my tree traversing skills are not so good.

Answer (score 0):

I have played a little with the code and I think I found *a* solution. Function `toTree` converts a nested list `x` into a list that can be supplied to `data.tree`.

```
depth <- function(x) ifelse(is.list(x), 1 + max(sapply(x, depth)), 0)

toTree <- function(x) {
  d <- depth(x)
  if(d > 1) {
    lapply(x, toTree)
  } else {
    children = lapply(names(x), function(nm) list(name=nm))
  }
}
```

Now, I can make a plot quickly. This time I use `FromListSimple`.

```
dt <- FromListSimple(toTree(x), nodeName = "x")
plot(dt)
```

I wonder if someone can come up with a more elegant solution.

Comment: That looks like a good approach. There are network packages which will achieve the same results you're after, but in the ones I've used you would need to convert data into the packages' own structures, which would be at least as involved as your method if not more. I'm not aware of anything that will plot directly from nested lists.